# slideToggle() not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Currently I have a onclick function that toggles a view in my html using .slideToggle(). But whenever I press the button to trigger this event, it doesnt do anything. Here is my code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="searchwrap"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</a>
<div class="col-sm-12 searchwrap" id="searchbox" style="display:none">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="card-box bg-lightdark border-3">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                  <label>Type</label>
                  <select id="ftype" class="form-control filter" name="ftype" data-column="5">
                    <option value="">All Types</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-sm-3 m-t-30">
                  <button type="button" id="btnsearch" name="btnsearch" class="btn btn-info btn-sm waves-inverse m-b-5"> Search <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button>
                  <a class="btn btn-inverse btn-trans btn-sm waves-inverse m-b-5" id="reset">Reset</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#searchwrap").click(function(e){ ('.searchwrap').slideToggle(); console.log("press");});
 });
```

I've also added a `console.log("press")` in the jquery and it doesnt show anything when clicked.

Fiddle: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-night-w8j03?file=/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show your code :

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#searchwrap").click(function(e){ ('.searchwrap').slideToggle(); console.log("press");});
 });
```

You dont close script tag and you dont use jquery symbol for your searchwrap class.

Try this

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#searchwrap").click(function(e){ $('.searchwrap').slideToggle(); console.log("press");});
 });
</script>
```

Comment: No this did not work. I have added a fiddle in my question to get a better idea

Comment: In your fiddle i see `".searchwrap".slideToggle();`
Like i say it's  `$(".searchwrap").slideToggle();`